# sqlite: dropping a table in a transaction?

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple, single table sqlite3 database file that has exactly one table.  There are no keys, foreign or domestic.  There are no triggers.  I have the following workflow:

If the database file exixts open it.

- Start exclusive transaction
- Select all rows from the table in order.
- Operate on each row.
- Delete each operated-on row.
- When done, count the number of remaining rows in the table, if 0 then DROP the table then unlink the database file
- Commit or Rollback the transaction

The drop-table always fails with the message that the table is locked.  I've seen a couple of other posts that suggest that there could be open statement handles or other cruft lying around.  Since I am using "sqlite_exec()"s for all of this I do not have any open DB anything except the DB handle itself.

Is drop table not allowed in transactions?

Comment: Are you using shared cache mode?

Comment: I did not specifically set that mode.  Is it on by default?

Answer (score 0):

When dropping a table, you get the "table is locked" message when there is still some active cursor on the table, i.e., when you did not finalize a statement (or did not close a query object in whatever language you're using).